# "No manual entry for [filename]" error, when trying to view my man page

Tags: linux, shell, vim, manpage

I'm creating a man page with Vim for something I made, but when I try to view it with the command:

```
man testScript.1
```

I get the error "**No manual Entry testScript.1**"

However, if I use:

```
cat *testScript.1
```

I can see the contents of that file listed.

This is what little code I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

.TH Testingjanne 1 "24 April 2019" "Version 1"
.sh NAME
Testingjanne - To test Janne
.SH SYNOPSIS
.B [-d] [-e] [-f
.I filename
.B ]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I see the man page as a man page?

Comment: You don't use `man cat.1` to view the man page of `cat`, do you? Why did you think you needed to add `.1` to view your own page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view your man page with:

```
man testScript
```

for example, if I do:

```
echo foo > /usr/share/man/man1/padawin.1
```

Then, the following works:

```
man padawin
```

Comment: I tried this, but permission is denied for some reason and sudo doesn’t seem to work

Comment: if your file is in a `man/man1/` directory in your `$PATH` (please someone confirm or correct me, as technically `$PATH` is for executable), it should just work.

Comment: Okay, I’ll try moving the file to man1